# Two simultaneous Schengen visa applications at the same time

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I live in the UK.
I need to apply for two separate business trips: first in Sweden, second in Germany. The dates of these trips do not overlap, they are 1 month apart.

I know it is possible to apply for both trips in a single application if these trips are not longer than 2 months apart and the country you apply to is the main destination.

However, I can't do it this time because:

1. Sweden doesn't like to give multiple entrance visas, I tried several times before and got single entrance visa each time, even if I provided complete information about another upcoming Schengen trip.
2. The next German appointment slot is too far to have enough time before the Sweden trip.

I am a Russian citizen and we are allowed to have two passports at the same time.

I wonder if it's possible to apply for two countries at the same time. This means, applying for a first visa and, while my first application is in progress, applying for the second one.

Is it permitted to do? Will they reject my applications in this case?

Comment: I don’t know if this is possible but I suspect the process would at the very least link up the existence of two applications in [VIS](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-information-system_en)

Comment: Can you arrange the appointments so that you get your passport with Swedish visa before you apply for German visa? This will solve all the problems. Calculate when you can apply for Swedish visa, add typical processing time plus some margin and see if you can schedule German application slot after that.

Comment: I don’t think anything prohibits it, but it doesn’t mean it may not confuse them or pique their curiosity. You should also make sure they don’t think you’re trying to hide something. How many visas have you received in the last two years?

Comment: You mentioned you're allowed to have two passports but you did not mention whether you actually have two passports. Maybe your second passport info could help us to refine the answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any rules against this, but trying to hide the other application from each consulate (by using two passports) seems risky - they will likely find out in the VIS anyway, as mentioned above. It seems safer to explain the situation to each consulate and explain that you're also applying for another visa. But if you have 1 month between the two trips couldn't you apply for the second visa during that month?